# Problem with side-expanding div on hover div sticking out of it. - Angular

Tags: angular, animation

Im trying to achieve something described in my title.
Normalny most of div are hidden outside screen, but small part of it sticking out on the screen.
In my case, I need to expand on hover on this small part and disband when mouse is moved out outside whole div. This is example what I want:

[I want it!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nftcs.gif)

But currently it works (or jiggling) like this:

[But i got this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLgRr.gif)

There is my current code in Angular:

component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BookingRatingModel } from './booking-rating';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-booking-section',
  templateUrl: './booking-section.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./booking-section.component.scss']
})
export class BookingSectionComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() bookingRating: BookingRatingModel = new BookingRatingModel(10, 'Nie do opisania');

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  openDetails(){
    const rating = document.getElementById('rating');
    if(rating)
      rating.style.right = "28rem"
    const ratingDetails = document.getElementById('rating-details');
    if(ratingDetails)
      ratingDetails.style.right = "0"
  }

  closeDetails(){
    const rating = document.getElementById('rating');
    if(rating)
      rating.style.right = "0"
    const ratingDetails = document.getElementById('rating-details');
    if(ratingDetails)
      ratingDetails.style.right = "-28rem"
  }
}
```

component.html:

```
<div 
    class="rating"
    id="rating"
    (mouseenter)='openDetails()'
    (mouseleave)='closeDetails()'>
    <div class="upper">
        <div class="title">{{"Sprawdź opinie" | uppercase}}</div>
    </div>
    <mat-icon class="icon">star</mat-icon>
    <div class="number">{{bookingRating.getNumber()}}</div>
</div>
<div 
    class="rating-details" 
    id="rating-details"
    (mouseleave)='closeDetails()'>
</div>
```

I tried 3 approaches to fix it:

- first, just remove closeDetails on rating element, but then I just can leave whole section expanded by leaving window by this div
- second, add delay to animations (0,3s), but when I move out mouse during delay, then whole div still be expanded
- using mouseover and mouseout doesn't change anything, just making more calls

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The trick is simple. When side div is expanded, the whole screen is under overlay (a little bit darker). So I added overlay to my page when div is expanded, and made code in component.ts looks like this:

```
async openDetails(){
    const rating = document.getElementById('rating');
    if(rating)
      rating.style.right = "28rem"
    const ratingDetails = document.getElementById('rating-details');
    if(ratingDetails)
      ratingDetails.style.right = "0"
    const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
    if(overlay)
      overlay.style.display = "inline-block";
  }

  closeDetails(){
    const rating = document.getElementById('rating');
    if(rating)
      rating.style.right = "0"
    const ratingDetails = document.getElementById('rating-details');
    if(ratingDetails)
      ratingDetails.style.right = "-28rem"
    const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
    if(overlay)
      overlay.style.display = "inline-block";
  }
```

And html:

```
<div
    class="overlay"
    id="overlay"
    (mouseenter)='closeDetails()'>
</div>
<div 
    class="rating"
    id="rating"
    (mouseenter)='openDetails()'>
    <div class="upper">
        <div class="title">{{"Sprawdź opinie" | uppercase}}</div>
    </div>
    <mat-icon class="icon">star</mat-icon>
    <div class="number">{{bookingRating.getNumber()}}</div>
</div>
<div 
    class="rating-details" 
    id="rating-details">
</div>
```

Now it's working like I want, I hope it helps somebody in future.